# (GXT) Change registration in ALL Children of Popup Panel

Tags: java, gxt

I have the following Problem in my GXT-Application:

In a Popup-Panel, I have a bunch of different fields, which are to be saved in a Databse (see picture)

[image]

I would add a new feature, which recogizes changes in the Children of this Popup-Panel. For this reason, I added a Change-Event to the Popup-Panel:

```
        editorPanel.addHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
             Info.display("Change","Now");
            
        }
      }, ChangeEvent.getType());
```

My Problem is now, that this only works with DataFields but not with Comboboxes. As far as I understood, this is due to the fact, that Comboboxes do not have a Change-Event but a Select-Event.
And here is my question: Is there an elegant way to gat those changes on the Level of the Popup-Panel or do I have to thriger the change event by every selection?

Sincerely,

Erik

Comment: Why not using GWT's Editor framework?

Comment: that could work, thanks